# Entity Framework 6.1 Discriminator TPH

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, downcast

I am looking to implement Table-per-Hierarchy using EF6 similar to the instructions found here:
[example](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph#7667933).

I have an abstract base class of *User* with the following derived types:

- Student
- Contact
- Instructor

When I examine the database table *Users* the *discriminator* column value is **(Undefined)** when I pass a student object into my *Save* method below.  Instead I would expect the value to be *Student*.  Otherwise my data is saved correctly in both the *Users* and *Students* tables.

While troubleshooting the problem I added a UserType enumerator Get property to the classes to ensure that I am casting from *User* to *Student*.

In my *UserRepository* class my *Save* method is below.

```
    public void Save(User user)
    {
      if (Exists(user.Id))
        UpdateUser(user);
      else
      {
        switch (user.Role)
        {
          case UserType.Role.Base:
           _db.Users.Add(user);
            break;
          case UserType.Role.Student:
           _db.Users.Add(user as Student);
           break;
         case UserType.Role.Instructor:
           _db.Users.Add(user as Instructor);
           break;
         case UserType.Role.Contact:
           _db.Users.Add(user as Contact);
           break;
       }
     }
     _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

## Failed Alternative

I've tried code like the following to explicitly create a new *Student*.

```
    private void MapToStudent(User user)
    {
     _db.Users.Add(new Student()
     {
       FirstName = user.FirstName,
       LastName = user.LastName,
       //...
      });
    }
```

## Question

I am not downcasting correctly?  Or rather what is the proper/preferred way to save subclasses using EF?

## User Base Class

```
      public abstract class User
      {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         //...
      }

      internal class UserNotFound: User 
      { 
        public override UserType.Role Role 
        { 
          get 
            { 
             return UserType.Role.Base; 
            } 
        }
      }

      public class Student : User 
      {
         //...
         public override UserType.Role Role 
         {
           get { return UserType.Role.Student; }          
         }
      }

      public class Contact : User 
      {
         //...
         public override UserType.Role Role 
         {
           get { return UserType.Role.Contact; }          
         }
      }

      public class Instructor : User 
      {
         //...
         public override UserType.Role Role 
         {
           get { return UserType.Role.Instructor; }          
         }
      }
```

## DatabaseContext Mapping

```
      public class DatabaseContext : Context
      {
          protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
          {
              modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Students");
              modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().ToTable("Contacts");
              modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>().ToTable("Instructors");
          }
      }
```

Comment: I think the problem is your base type is not Abstract.

Comment: @ErikPhilips my _User_ class is specified as: `public abstract class User`

Comment: Then this code should not exist: `case UserType.Role.Base: _db.Users.Add(user);`. However, how is `user.Role` value set?

Comment: `internal class UserNotFound: User { public override UserType.Role Role { get { return UserType.Role.Base; } } }` is the simplistic case of my null object of _User_.  I am overriding the property in each subclass and setting it according to its matching enumerator value. for @ErikPhilips

Comment: For future reference, it's best not to add code to the comment, but to you actual question (you can edit it as much as you'd like) so other reads can get a full comprehension of your question without the need to read all the comments.

Comment: I would also ask that you show the code that defines your TPH inheritance (or are you using Database First?)  What happens if you create a save method for a specific subclass and call it directly (for testing), does it create the discriminator?

Comment: All your Entities are mapped to table *Students*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your mappings are incorrect for TPH.  The linked example in your questions shows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<BillingDetail>()
    .Map<BankAccount>(m => m.Requires("BillingDetailType").HasValue("BA"))
    .Map<CreditCard>(m => m.Requires("BillingDetailType").HasValue("CC"));
}
```

which modeled after your question might look like:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .Map<Student>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("STU"))
    .Map<Instructor>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("INS"));
```

Comment: I was mixing my methodologies between TPH and TPT, so when my simple _Administrator_ class was being inserted it was using the *Discriminator* column, while the other subclasses do not use the column and instead  placed their data into separate appropriate tables. [concise documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.4)